# Fama MacBeth regression pmg function error in R

Tags: r, regression, plm

I've been trying to run a Fama Macbeth regression using the pmg function for my data "Dev_Panel" but I keep getting this error message:

```
Fehler in pmg(BooktoMarket ~ Returns + Profitability + BEtoMEpersistence,  : 
  Insufficient number of time periods
```

I've read in other posts on here that this could be due to NAs in the data. But I've already removed these from the panel.
Additionally, I've used the pmg function on the data frame "Em_Panel" for which I have undertaken the exact same data cleaning measures as for the "Dev_Panel". The regression for this panel worked, but it only produces a coefficient for the intercept. The other coefficients are NA.

Here's the code I used for the Em_Panel:

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)

Em_Panel <- read.csv2("Em_Panel.csv", na="NA")
FMR_Em <- pmg(BooktoMarket~Returns+Profitability+BEtoMEpersistence, Em_Panel, index = c("companyID", "years"))
```

And here's the code for the Dev_Panel:

```
Em_Panel <- read.csv2("Dev_Panel.csv", na="NA")
FMR_Dev <- pmg(BooktoMarket~Returns+Profitability+BEtoMEpersistence, Dev_Panel, index = c("companyID", "years"))
```

Since this seemingly is a problem concerning my data I will gladly provide it:

http://www.filedropper.com/empanel

http://www.filedropper.com/devpanel

Thank you so much for any help!!!

**Edit**
After switching the arguments as suggested the error is now produced by the Dev_Panel and not the Em_Panel.
Also the regression for the Em_Panel now only provides a coefficient for the intercept. The other coefficients are NA.

Comment: Given the error message "*Insufficient number of time periods*", how many time periods do you have in each of your cleaned data sets
?

Comment: I've got data for 14.023 time periods. I've also conducted the regression on data set with less time periods and didn't get a error message. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Switch the values you supply to the `index` argument. The names imply they should be switched as individual incomes is placed 1st and time index 2nd.

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks for the help. I've switched the arguments in my regression equation and now the error message switched from the Em_Panel to the Dev_Panel. So the problem still seems to lie somewhere in my data. 
Also the regression results for Em_Panel now only produces a coefficient for the intercept. The other coefficients are NA.